# Disallow cast to primitive

Tags: typescript

I want to specify object type in such way that any operation, casting it to primitive type is disallowed.

I can disable explicit `toString` call, but other operations like interpolation and concatenation are still compiling. How can I disable them too?

```
var x: { toString: unknown } = Object.create(null);

var s1 = `${x}`
var s2 = "" + x
var s3 = x.toString() // Object is of type 'unknown'.
```